# How to find and change Java compiler option in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code (VSC) and I come from Eclipse. VSC tells me 2 errors on my project:

- > Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
- > The compiler compliance specified is 1.5 but a JRE 1.8 is used.

Same as in Eclipse, I am looking for a preferences window to change the level of Java compiler (from 1.5 to 1.8 in my case) but I can't find it. I can only see files everywhere. The menu Preferences show many settings but nothing for the Java compiler.

Comment: Visual Studio Code does not have built-in Java support like Eclipse does. If you are looking for features specific to any language they will be provided by extensions. Are you already using an extension for Java? Have you looked at the documentation/readme for that extension?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/28) has helpful information.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Thank for your help. I am on MacOS with Microsoft java Extension pack...

Comment: Using all your answers, I realized that the error was on a project made of Javascript Angular, no need of Java. Then I deleted the directory ".settings" and file ".classpath".. and these 2 errors disappear.

Answer (score 29):

VS Code does not have built-in support for Java projects. You need to install specific Java extensions and configure them to specify the correct Java JDK version. Depending on the extension, you can specify the version by either setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or by setting the `java.home` setting:

> After installing the JDK, you would need to configure your environment
> for Java development. The most common way is to [set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html) `JAVA_HOME`
> environment variable to the install location of the JDK while you can
> also use `java.home` setting in Visual Studio Code settings ([workspace or user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)) to configure it just for the editor.

I described the installation/setup steps in more detail below. It is mostly based on the [Visual Studio Code tutorial for Java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/).
Since the [OP commented that they are using macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859959/how-to-find-and-change-java-compiler-option-in-visual-studio-code/56861298#comment100334716_56859959), **this answer is focused on the Java extension for VS Code on Mac**. Also, note that depending on the version of the JDK you have installed, `java.home` might already be deprecated or has been completely removed, and `java.jdt.ls.java.home` should be used instead ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859959/how-to-find-and-change-java-compiler-option-in-visual-studio-code/56861298#comment134758393_56861298)). So, replace accordingly. [Lekia's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859959/how-to-find-and-change-java-compiler-option-in-visual-studio-code/56861298#comment126685981_56861298) provides a tip:

> you can find java properties including `java.home` from terminal `java -XshowSettings:properties -version`

---

### MacOS

First, you need to install the Microsoft [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack).

Upon installation, it will display the *Java Overview* tab, and automatically check for available Java SDKs. If it cannot find one, it will prompt you to download one. (The *Java Overview* and this *JDK Required* page seems to also auto-appear when you open/create a .java file).

[image: install JDK]

From the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_install-visual-studio-code-for-java), these JDK distributions should be supported: OpenJDK, Java SE from Oracle, Azul Zulu Enterprise. For this answer, I am using OpenJDK 11. Download and install the appropriate JDK.

Next, get the path to your JDK. Open a Terminal and then:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If you already have a `JAVA_HOME` env var set, I recommend not relying on it. I find that it is better to set the relevant `java.*` properties instead to configure Java specifically for VS Code (or for a particular workspace).

Now, open the VS Code Settings tab and look for the *Java: Home* setting:

[image: java: home]

You can modify either the *User* or *Workspace* setting. In the screenshot above, I am modifying my *User* settings, making the `java.home`/`java.jdt.ls.java.home` setting affect all Java projects. You can also modify the *Workspace* setting to configure `java.home` differently for each workspace.

Click on the *Edit in settings.json*, and add `java.home` (you'll know your extension was installed properly if `java.*` autocompletion is displayed).

[image: java.home]

Specify the path to the JDK you got earlier:

```
"java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home",
```

**Then restart VS Code**. When the *Java Overview* tab displays again, if you set the path correctly, it should not prompt you anymore to download a JDK, meaning it found your JDK. Try running a very basic HelloWorld.java application.

### Windows

If you are on Windows, they provide a special installer to help you get started:

> To help you get started quickly, we created a [special Installer of Visual Studio Code for Java developers](https://aka.ms/vscode-java-installer-win).
>
> **[Download Visual Studio Code Java Pack Installer](https://aka.ms/vscode-java-installer-win)**
>
> **Note**: The installer is currently only available for Windows. For other
> OS, please install those components (JDK, VS Code and Java extensions)
> individually. We're working on the macOS version, please stay tuned.

Comment: I am on MacOS. I tried to add the java.home in settings.json .. and restart VSC . no change. (how to add the snapshot here in comments?).

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a more detailed step-by-step description for setting-up the Java extension and `java.home`. Check that the path you set is correct.

Comment: `java.home` is missing in VS Code settings for Windows. Can't find the way to set it

Comment: @KonstantinAbakumov My answer that mentions `java.home` is for MacOS. I unfortunately don't use Windows or have access to a Windows machine, so can't help you there :(

Comment: Worked with setting the Env variable, thanks!

Comment: you can find java properties including java.home from terminal `java -XshowSettings:properties -version`

Comment: 2023-06-07 update: ```java.home``` is deprecated use ```java.jdt.ls.java.home``` instead

Answer (score 5):

In visual studio code, you need to change your compliance version in below file

- **Filename:** `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`
- **path:** `Your_project_directory/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

(`.settings` will be hidden in file explorer will be visible only in vs code.)

Also, change from 1.7 to 1.8 in the file. 1.8 is the java version based upon the java version input the value

[image: Refer the Image For info]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the file you said, I changed it to 1.8, restarted VSC but problem still here. I don't know if my changes are taken into account (is restart sufficient ? or shall I send any command ?)

Comment: Shall i know? whether you have built project with maven or used regular java project

Answer (score 5):

Add to `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "<location-of-your-preferred-jdk>"
}
```

Note: This is only for the current project.

Comment: I had some existing files in the `.vscode/settings.json`, do you think the following insertion is correct:
```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#0D3512",
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#124B19",
        "titleBar.activeForeground": "#F5FDF6"
    },
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot"

}

```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using all your answers, I realized that the error was on a project made of Javascript Angular, no need of Java. Then I deleted the directory ".settings" and file ".classpath".. and these 2 errors disappear.

Thank to all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are a lot of answers here. IMO it's a little confusing because it seems like there are multiple Java Plugins, and multiple ways to set the JDK / JVM for each plugin.

I seem to be using the Redhat plugin. If using the Redhat plugin and a JDK < 17 then I found the way to set JVMs here: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#java.configuration.runtimes

Answer (score 1):

Seems like setting the array "java.configuration.runtimes" in the settings.json file to all the JDKs you've installed lets VS Code know which JDKs you have installed on your system. Then when you open a new project that enforces sourceCompatibility, you will receive a notification asking whether to use the appropriate JDK (which VS Code now knows about). If you don't see this notification, you could just edit the "java.import.gradle.java.home" setting yourself to point to the correct JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
My pom.xml file was not correct. If you use Maven, take a other look on that file.

For me, it was in the ".settings" folder (it should be in your Java project). There's some "org.eclipse" files in there. You just need to change the 1.5 to 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a jdk8 in environment and I need to compile the java file to class file in Jre 1.7 version. The class files major.minus version need 0x33.

So I need to use the vscode-java to create the class files. But the vscode do not has the setting for compiler. The eclipse project has a setting file in .setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs. [Settings Global Preferences](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Settings-Global-Preferences)

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.7
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.7
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.7
```

This file can change the compiler option in eclipse jdt.

The vscode-java extension has a setting option to use specific setting file. We can add the code below to the .vscode/setting.json to change the java compiler target version.

```
"java.settings.url": ".settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs",
```

As a result the class file compiled has a 0x33 jre major.minor version.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using Java 21 in VSCode with Gradle on WSL. VSCode has an internal Java 17 runtime (March 2024) [as described here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gradle/blob/develop/README.md). In order to let VSCode use your default Java 21 installation add the 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' setting, for me it looks like this:

```
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64"
```

Settings -> 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' -> 'edit in settings.json'